# Не удается получить компонент Animator

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Кто-то сталкивался со странной проблемой, хочу просто получить компонент, а тут ошибонька странная :

`animator = GetComponent<Animator>();` - выдает ошибку `Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Animator' to 'UnityEngine.Animation'`

В чем прикол?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

'UnityEngine.Animator' to 'UnityEngine.Animation' "

animator  типа **Animation** а должен быть **Animator** выставьте правильный типа, для переменной.

Comment: так мне именно и нужен Animator  а не  Animation

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HqbRqM5.png вот тут надо поменять

Comment: Спасибо, опять невнимательность моя, добра и удачи тебе !

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста).